# How to set IO priority for a Rust process?

Tags: rust, process, io

I am trying to increase the IO priority of the current thread so it can run IO operations faster because it iterates over a directory and fetches the metadata of the files, but I cannot really find any way to increase the IO priority. There is the crate [ioprio](https://crates.io/crates/ioprio) but it is only for Linux, while I need to do it in Windows.

Comment: [This answer](https://superuser.com/a/226419) plus [this api](https://microsoft.github.io/windows-docs-rs/doc/windows/Win32/System/Threading/fn.SetPriorityClass.html) seems like the way to go.